# XCode clang failed with exit code 254

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, xcode4.2

Im Trying to build/run a iOS app on the iPhone 6.1 Simulator, however im getting this error. 
Ive looked around and tried evertything ive found but nothing has helped.

This will build on other computers, but not this one.
Im completley new to iOS development so I dont know where to start.

Any help is apreciated, here is the error message:

```
CompileC /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o CorsageCreations/AppDelegate.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd "/Volumes/VMware Shared Folders/iosProj/corsage-ios/CorsageCreations"
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0 -iquote /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/CorsageCreations-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/CorsageCreations-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/CorsageCreations-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/CorsageCreations-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -I/Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-F/Volumes/VMware Shared Folders/iosProj/corsage-ios/CorsageCreations/../../../../../../../Desktop/FbShare" "-F/Volumes/VMware Shared Folders/iosProj/corsage-ios/CorsageCreations/../../.." -F/Users/GuestUser/Desktop -include /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/CorsageCreations-Prefix-fjwwmvkmbxepoldfyuusggxlzkzu/CorsageCreations-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.dia -c "/Volumes/VMware Shared Folders/iosProj/corsage-ios/CorsageCreations/CorsageCreations/AppDelegate.m" -o /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o

0  clang 0x0000000100c57bb2 main + 12932498
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments:             /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -triple i386-apple-ios5.0.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name AppDelegate.m -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -target-cpu yonah -target-linker-version 136 -g -coverage-file /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.2 -dependency-file /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.d -MT dependencies -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -iquote /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/CorsageCreations-generated-files.hmap -iquote /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/CorsageCreations-project-headers.hmap -include-pch /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/CorsageCreations-Prefix-fjwwmvkmbxepoldfyuusggxlzkzu/CorsageCreations-Prefix.pch.pth -D DEBUG=1 -I /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/CorsageCreations-own-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/CorsageCreations-all-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -I /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Volumes/VMware Shared Folders/iosProj/corsage-ios/CorsageCreations/../../../../../../../Desktop/FbShare -F/Volumes/VMware Shared Folders/iosProj/corsage-ios/CorsageCreations/../../.. -F/Users/GuestUser/Desktop -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/_z/1x7mbrnx6f310pngnn97l5_00000gn/T/clang-module-cache -O0 -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -std=gnu99 -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=ios-5.0.0 -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fobjc-exceptions -fexceptions -fpascal-strings -fdiagnostics-show-option -fasm-blocks -serialize-diagnostic-file /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.dia -o /Users/GuestUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CorsageCreations-bisxifklumnvgbghbkjqvehvmshk/Build/Intermediates/CorsageCreations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CorsageCreations.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o -x objective-c /Volumes/VMware Shared Folders/iosProj/corsage-ios/CorsageCreations/CorsageCreations/AppDelegate.m 
1.  /Volumes/VMware Shared Folders/iosProj/corsage-ios/CorsageCreations/CorsageCreations/ArrayObject.h:46:33: current parser token ':'
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: i386-apple-darwin12.3.0
Thread model: posix
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced the same issue. It turned out that the host's folders shared by VMWare were read-only (even though that the read-only attribute from VM settings was unchecked).

Have you tried running sample xcode projects or copying code you're referencing to the VM?

I ended up sharing my folders using regular file sharing built in Windows 8.

Comment: How did you share from Windows for access from OS X?

I have the same issue, segmentation fault when compiling in share folders done by VM Ware.

Comment: From what I remember, turning on folder sharing from Windows on specific folder was enough. The PC was showing up in the networking  section on Mac.

Comment: I'm sharing through Windows share as advised, and still getting the segfault.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. I was running my Example project keeping it in VMWare Shared Folder's sub folder. And that was the reason, which made the above issue.

I copied my example project which I wanted to compile and Run (or even build which gave the above error) and pasted it into the Mac OS X(Mavericks) Desktop which was running on the VMWare Workstation 9.0. Then tried running it and it worked!

Hope this answer would be helpful to someone else out there!
Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

You made `clang` (the compiler) segfault (`Segmentation fault: 11`). Nothing you can do about it (unless you want to patch `clang`), you could however investigate the issue by passing the `-v` option when compiling.

I'm not absolutely sure, but I would say it is because your are developing inside a virtual machine. As far as I know OS X is only supported as a guest OS in VMWare Fusion 5+, and even then it is rather unstable.

Comment: I thought it could be that as well, but its running on this ssame virtual machine on another pc.

Comment: And I tried the -v option and it didnt seem to make any difference

Comment: Are compiling the **exact same** code on an **exact same** vm ? Alos what version of OS X are you using ?

Comment: Sadly yes it is, I dont quite understand why it wont work. The vm is OS X 10.8 64bit (Mountain Lion)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with OS X, not iOS, so it seems not platform dependent.
Specifically, the compiler did not create the .o file and did not report any syntax errors.

The problem was caused by a property with a void type:

@property(readonly) void  reset;

Removing the property fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a similar problem, and shows a possible cause. Try putting this into a .m file and compiling it:

```
 typedef struct{
    int workAroundAsStructCannotBeOtherwiseEmpty;
    float points [];
} arrayOfFloats;

@property arrayOfFloats someArrayOfFloats;
```

Interestingly, won't compile without the "workaround" line. If you change it to float points [10] it compiles fine.